# Query that will count text values and return the row with the lowest count value (min)?

Tags: sql, count, min, having-clause

Wondering if someone could assist with this query, I need to write a query that will count stores, based on that the state location, then display the state location with the lowest count for the country.  Each country code must only be represented once.

this is what I have so far :-

```
select
  CountryRegionCode]
  , [StateProvinceCode]
  , COUNT(PSP.StateProvinceID) as [No. of Stores]
from [Sales].[Store] as SS
  inner join [Person].[BusinessEntityAddress] as PBEA on SS.BusinessEntityID = PBEA.BusinessEntityID
  inner join [Person].[Address] as PA on PBEA.AddressID = PA.AddressID
  inner join [Person].[StateProvince] as PSP on PA.StateProvinceID = PSP.StateProvinceID
group by 
  CountryRegionCode
  ,StateProvinceCode
having
  count(PSP.StateProvinceID) = 
   (select min(a.cnt)
     from (select count(PSP.StateProvinceID) as cnt from [Sales].[Store] as SS2
       inner join [Person].[BusinessEntityAddress] as PBEA2 on SS2.BusinessEntityID = PBEA2.BusinessEntityID
       inner join [Person].[Address] as PA2 on PBEA2.AddressID = PA2.AddressID
       inner join [Person].[StateProvince] as PSP2 on pa2.StateProvinceID = PSP2.StateProvinceID
  group by 
    CountryRegionCode) as a)
  order by CountryRegionCode
```

I've attached the current output, how do I restrict the output to only show the lines highlighted in yellow? Eg the state with the lowest store count for each country.

(I'm not allowed to use the top clause)

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `min()` function

```
  with cte as
    (
    select
      CountryRegionCode]
      , [StateProvinceCode]
      , COUNT(PSP.StateProvinceID) as no_of_store
    from [Sales].[Store] as SS
      inner join [Person].[BusinessEntityAddress] as PBEA on SS.BusinessEntityID = PBEA.BusinessEntityID
      inner join [Person].[Address] as PA on PBEA.AddressID = PA.AddressID
      inner join [Person].[StateProvince] as PSP on PA.StateProvinceID = PSP.StateProvinceID
    group by 
      CountryRegionCode
      ,StateProvinceCode
    having
      count(PSP.StateProvinceID) = 
       (select min(a.cnt)
         from (select count(PSP.StateProvinceID) as cnt from [Sales].[Store] as SS2
           inner join [Person].[BusinessEntityAddress] as PBEA2 on SS2.BusinessEntityID = PBEA2.BusinessEntityID
           inner join [Person].[Address] as PA2 on PBEA2.AddressID = PA2.AddressID
           inner join [Person].[StateProvince] as PSP2 on pa2.StateProvinceID = PSP2.StateProvinceID
      group by 
        CountryRegionCode) as a)


    ), cte2 as
   (
   select *,
     min(no_of_store) over(partition by CountryRegionCode order by 
       CountryRegionCode ) as rn from cte
    ) select * from cte2 where rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you, however that did not change the output.  All 65 rows were still returned.  I'm looking for the state by country with the lowest store count

Comment: @Amaranth does that image your query output? my query based on that , so that returns your image output then definitely it should work

Comment: the query output sample attached is what is happening, not what I hope to achieve.  the preferred query output will show about 10 rows, and will only have one row for each country

Comment: @Amaranth if one country each then the query would be different i changed it in answer check i tnow

Comment: I also need to show the state province code in the output.  How do I insert the state province code as the second column, without adding extra rows.  thank you for your help thus far :)

Comment: @Amaranth code edited you can check it work as you expected

Comment: No sorry :(  I believe that there is something wrong with the having clause.  I'm trying to achieve    "having count (state province ID) = min(count(state province ID)).  I'm not sure what the correct syntax is for that pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select cs.*
from (select CountryRegionCode, StateProvinceCode,
             count(*) as num_stores,
             rank() over (partition by CountryRegionCode order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from [Sales].[Store] ss join
           [Person].[BusinessEntityAddress] pbea
      pbeaon ss.BusinessEntityID = pbea.BusinessEntityID inner join
         [Person].[Address] pa
         on pbea.AddressID = pa.AddressID inner join
         [Person].[StateProvince] psp
         on pa.StateProvinceID = psp.StateProvinceID
      group by CountryRegionCode, StateProvinceCode
     ) cs
where seqnum = 1;
```

If there are ties, this returns all the states with the largest values within a country.  If you want only one, then use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.